# Regex with first cap char + digits

Tags: c#, regex

I hit a wall with this one so looking for help.

My strings must be in the following format:

```
777_7.70B_A777777
777_7.7B_A777777
777_7.7_A777777
```

I got the first 2 groups working just fine but I just cannot get the last group to work.
This is my regex:

```
^\\d{3}_\\d{1,2}[.]\\w{1,3}_\\[A-Z0-9]{7}$
```

Trying to get **[A-Z0-9]{7}** to work for **A777777**... at least.
What would be awesome is to have a rule that allows only one cap char in the beginning followed by 6 digits... but that's a gravy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^\d{3}_\d{1,2}\.[^\W_]{1,3}_[A-Z0-9]{7}$
^\d{3}_\d{1,2}\.[^\W_]{1,3}_[A-Z]\d{6}$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/j1Uhaz/1/) and [this regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/j1Uhaz/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `_` - a `_` char
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[^\W_]{1,3}` - one to three word chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you only need to allow ASCII chars, compile the regex with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I thought I was a lot closer.  You saved me a ton of time!